# Android retrofit repeat request after token expired?

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit to commuicate to my server.
I have to call the login endpoint first, then I got a cookie (auth. token), which I store automatically, and the following requests are being authorized.
This 'session' expires if there is no request for 1 hour.

How should I do the automatic re-authenticating?
Obviously it's not a good idea, that I ping the login endpont with the username/password before every "real" request, to be sure that my client has not expired yet.

I tried adding interceptor to the okHttpClient, and check whether my "real" response (not the login) gets back code 401. In that case I should call the login endpoint, and after that, I have to repeat the "real" call.

How can I "save" the request, call login, and after that repeat the first request when I'm authenticated again?

```
private static Retrofit retrofit;

   public static Retrofit getClient( final Context context ) {

       if ( retrofit == null ) {
           ClearableCookieJar cookieJar =
                   new PersistentCookieJar(new SetCookieCache(), new SharedPrefsCookiePersistor(context));

           final OkHttpClient okHttpClient =
                   new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                           .followSslRedirects(false)
                           .followRedirects(false)
                           .cookieJar(cookieJar)
                           .addInterceptor(chain -> {

                               Request request = chain.request();
                               Response response = chain.proceed(request);

                               if ( response.code() == 401 ) {

                                   if ( !response.message().contains("Incorrect") ) {
                                      // THIS IS THE CASE, when I try to call an endpoint with expired token
                                      // I need to call login again, and then repeat this failed request
                                   }

                               }
                               return response;
                           })
                           .build();

           retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                           .baseUrl(URL)
                           .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                           .client(okHttpClient)
                           .build();
        }
       return retrofit;
   }
```

Obviously I can check manually every request's response code, and if it's 401, I call login, and when it's done, I call my request again. But I'm hoping that there is an easier (built-in solution with interceptors, so I don't have to implement this logic everywhere)

Comment: just make network call to login there where you catch expired token

Comment: Use authenticator.  See this link https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-authenticator/

Comment: Thanks, I didin't know that there was something like that, but this is exactly what I needed. I can't accept your answer in the comments  :/

Answer (score -1):

After login response, save the token, then carry this token to commuicate with server, so that user don't need to login again.

When app gets a response like "401:expired token" during any request, just delete the saved token and all the user data and show a dialog let user jump to LoginActivity. Then repeat.

Comment: I'm doing exactly that, but after 1 hour of no client-server communication, the token will expire. And this case I dont want the user to log in manually. If the user logged in successfully once, I save the datas, and make the login request automatically before the real request (if the token already expired)

Comment: @CookieMonster Ok I see, what you need is a Api that refresh the token, and this Api can never return "expired token", just send the old token, server returns the new one, if the request failed, still need to manually login. Normally we don' do this, we just set the token expired duration to a Week even a month.